# How much ram can this new computer hold?

Tags: memory, specifications, quad-core, barebone

There's a [barebone laptop](http://www.avadirect.com/product_details_parts.asp?PRID=24438) that I found on the internet, but I never build a barebone computer before, and the website says that it can hold a max of 32 GB of ram, but when you scroll down to the specs page, it says 16 GB max (4 per slot). Btw, I plan on using a quad core processor. I don't understand, is it 4x4gb max or 4x8gb or what?

EDIT: For those of you who won't visit the webpage...

On the top, it says

```
Up to 32GB DDR3 1600MHz memory
```

However, on the bottom, it says

```
SO-DIMM slots x 4 for DDR3 1600/1333/1066 MHz if the CPU is four cores
(2 slots on the motherboard front side and 2 slots on the rear side)
SO-DIMM slots x 2 for DDR3 1333/1066 MHz if the CPU is dual cores
**Maximum 16GB (Up to 4GB each slot)**
```

Comment: I'd bet it's 4 x 4gb

Comment: On the website, if you scroll down, it says that only 16 is allowed, even though it says 32 up top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSI themselves, it's the later (16GB max).

Main Memory
• SO-DIMM slots x 4 for DDR3 1600/1333/1066 MHz if the CPU is four cores
 (2 slots on the motherboard front side and 2 slots on the rear side)
• SO-DIMM slots x 2 for DDR3 1333/1066 MHz if the CPU is dual cores
• *Maximum 16GB* (Up to 4GB each slot)

Source: [MSIWhitebook.com](http://www.msiwhitebook.com/product_spec.asp?model=MS-16F32)

I'd go by that.

Answer (score 2):

I would trust the [manufacture website specification](http://www.msiwhitebook.com/product_spec.asp?model=MS-16F32) more than I would the AvaDirect website. In other words, looks like 16 GB max.